Can't checkout a branch because a submodule's commit is no longer on its remote
This is similar to Submodule commited branch no longer available but differnt such that its solution isn't applicable.
I just cloned a repo, and it has submodules, I have done a submodule update/init as well.
git clone ... foo && cd foo && git submodule update --init
I am on master, I want to checkout I want to checkout a branch bar.  When I try it fails; I have determined from the error and checking the repo's that git is unable to check out the submodule properly because the commit that the submodule pointed at is no longer in that repository.
For completeness the error is :

fatal: failed to unpack tree object 
error: Submodule 'x' could not be updated.
error: Cannot update submodule:
x
Aborting

I get the idea here, git can't do it because the submodule's commit hash can't be found and git doesn't want to put the working repository in a 'messed up state', however this seems to leave me with no way to fix it locally.
What can I do so I can update that submodule in the current repo to point at a valid commit?
Let's assume for the moment that

I don't have access to a box which already has either the submodule repo checked out with that commit in its history OR the current repo with that submodule at the appropriate state.
I don't want to go into github to fix this, because I want to have a solution purely in git


Out of curiosity, why does the commit that the submodule pointed to no longer exist? Was there a large history rewrite of the submodule repo at some point? In any case, I don't think there's anyway you can make past commits in the host repo reference valid commits in the submodule repo without a) re-writing the host repo history, or b) recovering a version of the submodule repo that contains the missing commit (or the necessary objects and metadata to reconstruct it), or c) cracking SHA1 to create a new commit with same ID as the old commit

@Brian61354270 appreciate comment a. I have no idea; and it doesn't really matter. For all I know it was on a branch that got deleted. I don't control that repo. B. I never expressed any desire to alter past commits, or rewrite history. I also have no ability to recover a version of that submodule repo. I could care less even if I could. Remember that submodules don't properly track branches, they track a commit, I'm fine with moving to the latest commit on the branch it was tracking. I don't care why it's gone or that it's gone. Not being able to check out the branch makes this painful to fix

Until someone gives a good answer the hack I used to get around this, which is absolutely deplorable, is to deinit the remote checkout the branch, delete the folder and then re-add it ( which re-clones) it.  This is abysmal and there simply must be a better way than this.  As such I am not accepting my own answer right away.
git submodule deinit x
git checkout <BRANCH>
git rm x
git submodule add <URL for x> x
git add .gitmodules
git add x
git commit -m'resetting submodule x'

and then eventually push it.
